# I need reporting Laravel package with pdf export option

Tags: php, laravel, report

I need a reporting Laravel package that i can link to my project to be able to generate php reports with pdf export option. Code example will be very helpful!

Comment: Stack overflow is not a coding service. Please post your best attempt at getting your code working, and the specific errors and problems that you run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many Laravel packages that you can use for reporting, the following package, I believe, is a good example:

[Smart Report Engine](https://mysqlreports.com)

A well-documented PHP reporting framework (with many code examples). It's available as a native PHP engine and as a laravel package. Here is a code example of how to use it to convert a SQL query into a report.

```
   $report = new ReportOptions(Constants::SRE_PUBLIC_REPORT, Constants::SRE_SQL,"SQL_01");
   $report->set_sql("select * from items where `Units_In_Stock` < 15 ")
          ->set_header("Header goes here")
          ->set_grouping(array("country"))                       
          ->label("id", "Product ID")
          ->select_all_fields();
   $engine = new CustomEngine($report);
   $report_path = $engine->create_report();
```

Using this engine you can generate public reports or integrate the engine with your existing login system to generate private reports. [Here is how](https://mysqlreports.com/examples/integrating-smart-report-engine-with-a-session-based-login-system/)

[More code examples are available here.](https://mysqlreports.com/examples/primary-usage-of-smart-report-engine/)